# I can't create a customer and I don't know why

Tags: php, stripe-payments, jsondecoder, error-log

On this page payment.php, I would like to create a customer for payment on stripe, but I have nothing in my page, nothing in the console, there is written NULL, I don't know how to make it work.

```
    <?php


    $token = $_POST['token'];
    $name = $_POST['nom'];


    require_once('assets/vendor/stripe/init.php');


// (switch to the live key later)
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_p5p8Apo5Mn2LIn1po1tg5tYe33df6vQf");

try
{
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
      "name" => $name,
      "source" => $token,
    ]);
  $reponse= json_decode($customer);
  var_dump($reponse);


}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  error_log("unable to sign up customer:" . $_POST['stripeEmail'].
    ", error:" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: A blank page is usually 500 Internal Server Error, which is a generic error message. Check your web server error logs to see if there's more information.

Comment: I tried my form again and now it says juste NULL

Comment: Try `var_dump($customer);` instead.

Comment: Yes i can see my object in my page but why in dashboard of stripe website in customers i don't see the client I just created

Comment: It shows with your code but not in the Stripe website? You'll have to contact them about that.

Comment: Can you try using this when logging your customer? 


    ob_start();
    var_dump($customer);
    error_log(ob_get_clean(), 4);

Comment: juste to be sur if i have this, it's means i created a customer ?
object(Stripe\Customer)#2 (23) { ["id"]=> string(18) "cus_GOcb5R0NIBoo8P" ["object"]=> string(8) "customer" ["address"]=> NULL ["balance"]=> int(0) ["created"]=> int(1576863247) ["currency"]=> NULL ["default_source"]=> string(29) "card_1FrpMYBvuKnZ8bxshlRhreO8" ["delinquent"]=> bool(false) ["description"]=> NULL ["discount"]=> NULL ["email"]=> NULL ["invoice_prefix"]=> string(8) "87DBC2EB" ["invoice_settings"]=> ............

Comment: You have an ID, so I would assume so.

Comment: I send them an email then thank you